# Count occurrences of number in two lists and return one list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to count the number of occurrences a 0 occurs in two lists together and save that number using python.  I am trying to put it into a third list using 'list comprehension' commands but I am not getting the output I want.

My two lists are:

```
list1 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
list2 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

So, anytime there is a 0 occuring in the same place in each list I would like to append '0' into a new list.  I would like to do the same thing with the ones.

the new list should look like:

```
newlist = [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1]
```

Thanks for the help in advance, I've been trying to figure out how to do this for several hours now to no avail!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension, like this:

```
answer = [x for x, y in zip(list1, list2) if x == y]
```

Alternatively, you can solve it *without* list comprehensions by using simple list operations:

```
answer = []
for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    if x == y:
        answer.append(x)
```

In both cases, `answer`will be:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[x or y for x,y zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[0 if x == (0,0) else 1 for x in zip(list1,list2)]
```

Comment: Won't this put in 1 for a (1,0) pair?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

If you want list consisting of `0` and `1` in order of **`0` or `1` appearing at the same position in both lists**, then you can use the following list comprehension:

```
result = [a for a, b in zip(list1, list2) if a==b]
```

### Test

Testing your values however:

```
>>> newlist = [a for a, b in zip(list1, list2) if a==b]
>>> newlist
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

you see that the result is not equal to what you have been expecting:

```
>>> newlist == [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
False
```

So the question for you is: is the expected result you have provided a correct one?

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
list2 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
temp = [ list1[i] if list1[i] == list2[i] else 2 for i in range( 0, len(list1) )]
answer = [value for value in temp if value != 2]
print( answer )
```